# Suppose R is a ring, in which for any nonzero a and b in R the equation ax=b has an answer. prove that R doesnt have left or right zero divisor.

Tags: ring-theory

My attempt:
by contradiction suppose 'a' (nonzero) is a zero divisor so there exists some 'b' (nonzero) which a.b=0
since ax=b has an answer so a(ax)=0 implies a.a(x)=0
now i have no idea.

Comment: Actually, it seems that this condition implies $R$ has an identity and moreover is a division ring.

Answer (score 3):

Assume for contradiction that $a\neq 0$ is a right zero divisor, with $c\neq 0$ such that $ca = 0$. By assumption, there is some $b\in R$ such that $cb\neq 0$ (such a $b$ must exist; take any $d\neq 0$ in the ring*, and let $b$ be the solution to $cx = d$). Now $ax = b$ has a solution, but $0 = cax = cb$ is a contradiction.

The same contradiction shows that there cannot be any left zero-divisor $c$ in our ring (let $c$ be a left zero-divisor with $ca = 0$ and again look at $cax = cb$).

*It may be that the ring just has the zero element. But then it clearly doesn't have zero divisors, so we're still good.

Comment: If you consider the elements $0,3,6$ modulo $9$ and end up with $c=3$ you will not be able to find such a $b$.

Comment: You need to use that $cx=a\neq 0$ for some $x$ to show that there is a non-zero product. Else $0,3,6$ modulo $9$ with $c=3$ shows that in general you can't assume that a non-zero element has a non-zero product.

Comment: @MarkBennet I think I fixed it.

Comment: @arthur Is 'x' which is the answer of ax=b necessarily exacly the same x which is the answer of cx=d?

Comment: @Arman_jr Not at all. The answer to $cx = d$ is $b$ (in other words, $cb = d$). The answer to $ax = b$ doesn't really matter except that it exists, meaning $a$ is a left $b$-divisor.

Comment: @arthur you mean that we must choose some d which cx=d gives us b?

Comment: @Arman_jr We have to make sure that we choose a $b$ such that $cb\neq 0$. We do that by picking an arbitrary $d\neq 0$ and solving $cx = d$. Letting $b$ be a solution to that equation, we know that $cb\neq 0$, which leads to a contradiction later.

Comment: @arthur We know that cx=d has a solution, but not exactly b. If we want to 'b' be the answer of it, then d could not be arbitary. am I right?

Comment: @Arman_jr We know it has at least one solution, and we pick one of them, and _call_ that solution $b$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87751/discussion-between-arman-jr-and-arthur).

Comment: @Arman_jr I do not like to discuss in chat. I know the site likes it, but I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the equation $ax=b$, $a\ne 0$, can be solved, then in particular the equation $ax=1$, where $1$ is the unit element, can be solved. So each element $a\ne 0$ has a multiplicative inverse.

But units are no zero divisors. Indeed, if $a\in R$ is a unit and $ab=0$, then $0 = a^{-1}0 = a^{-1}(ab) = (a^{-1}a)b=1b=b$.

Comment: R isnt necesaarily unitary, ie R doesnt have necessarily 1

Comment: Okay. So my solution is valid for unitary rings.

Comment: Choosing $b=a$, each nonzero $a$ has a right unit, $1_a$. Can we argue that $1_a=1_b$ for all nonzero $a,b$?

Comment: @bgins We also would need to show that $1_a$ is unique, and that $1_aa = a$. Might be possible, but seems difficult. Or someone might find a counterexample.

Comment: @Arthur Challenge accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to augment Wuestenfux's solution by demonstrating the ring has an identity.

Let $a$ be nonzero.  Then $ae=a$ for some $e$.  Then also $ay=e$ for some $y$. Stringing these together, $aay=ae=a$, so $R$ is [strongly regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring#Generalizations_and_specializations), and therefore a [reduced ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring).

With this, you can compute 
$(ea-a)^2=eaea-eaa-aea+aa=eaa-eaa-aa+aa=0$ so $ea=a$ as well.

Now let $b$ be any other nonzero element. There must exist $z$ such that $az=b$. You immediately have $eb=eaz=az=b$.

We similarly compute that $(be-b)^2=bebe-beb-bbe+bb=bbe-bb-bbe+bb=0$ so $be=b$ as well.

So $e$ is the identity for the ring.  At this point you can either proceed as Wuestenfux has outlined, or else observe that the condition makes the ring a simple right module over itself, so therefore it is a division ring, and has no nonzero zero divisors.